# Is there any way to control where the output file of a T4 is generated to?

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-generation, t4

I would like to generate C# code for silverlight but I dont have access to some dll's that would make my T4 code more powerful. Is there anyway to have my T4 template in a C# Class Library and have it generate a file in the Silverlight Class Library?

Comment: Why not generate your code into the class library, but reference it from the SilverLight application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use T4 Toolbox for this, [here is how](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/). I remember this topic coming up a few months ago on the [T4 Toolbox forum on CodePlex](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx); someone used this approach successfully specifically with a silverlight project.

Oleg

Answer (score 0):

You can run TextTransform.exe and pass it a template file that would generate Silverlight class with no problem.